# Update Directive Scope After Controller Service Call

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a controller, which calls a service that performs a $http.get

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, mService) {

    $scope.chair;

    myService.getData().then(function (data) {
        $scope.chair = data.chairID;
    });

});
```

Within the scope of the controller, i have a directive for which i am trying to pass in the value of $scope.chair:

```
<section ng-controller="mycontroller">

    <my-directive data-chair="chair"></my-directive>

</section>
```

And within myDirective.js

```
restrict: 'E',
replace: true,
templateUrl: 'app/some-file.html',
scope: {
    chair: '='
},
controller: [ '$scope', function ($scope) {
    alert('got chair : ' + $scope.chair);
    ....
```

However with the above, i see undefined when alerting ('got chair : ' + $scope.chair);

Within the contoller, if i hardcode chair:

```
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, mService) {

    $scope.chair = 'hello';

    myService.getData().then(function (data) {
        $scope.chair = data.chairID;
    });

});
```

My directive will display `hello`.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 1):

"Chair" internal variable might not be set when you try to access it in the directive. It also seems that you load the value asynchronously via your service.

You'll need to attach a watch in your directive. The callback you pass to the watch will be invoked in the next angular $digest phase after a value change of the "chair" scope variable.

```
...
controller: [ '$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('chair', function(chairValue) {
        if (chairValue === undefined) return;

        // There is a value.
        alert('got chair : ' + $scope.chair);
    });
}]
```

*This code will lead to the callback being called every time the value changes.*

If you don't want to handle value changes clear the watch after the value is stable (*different from undefined*). This will lead to better performance if you have complex views with many bindings and watches.

```
...
controller: [ '$scope', function ($scope) {
    var unwatch = $scope.$watch('chair', function(chairValue) {
        if (chairValue === undefined) return;

        // There is a value.
        alert('got chair : ' + $scope.chair);
        unwatch();
    });
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/some-file.html',
    scope: {
        chair: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       alert('got chair : ' + scope.chair);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, however i need to access it within the controller, not link